# How to generate a pdf from xml using ironpython script

Tags: ironpython

i was trying to create a plugin which has to be written in ironpython which can convert data from a XML file to pdf on click of a button in an app. can anyone tell the best possible to way to do it...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have to use the C# version of the [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library. You can reference from IronPython using `clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath` followed by something like `import iText`. I haven't used iText in years so I'm not sure what namespace it's in, but that's what you want to import.

The XML can be read using the standard `System.Xml` classes; how you translate it to PDF is up to you.